# enviar array de html por ajax

Tags: html, ajax

tengo el siguiente código

```
function insertarRequerimiento(){
divResultado = document.getElementById('divrequerimiento');

id_contacto = document.getElementById('id_contacto_solicita[]').value;

alert(id_contacto);
ajax=objetoAjax();
ajax.open("POST", "vista/datalist/insertrequerimiento.php");
ajax.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (ajax.readyState==4) {
        divResultado.innerHTML = ajax.responseText
    }
}
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
ajax.send("id_contacto="+id_contacto);  }
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente: como pasar el valor de `id_contacto_solicita[]`a la variable `id_contacto` y mandarlo a la función  `ajax.send("id_contacto="+id_contacto);` 
 la variable `id_contacto_solicita[]` es de html de un multiple select. antes solo mandaba un dato un id, pero ahora mando multiples id, y solo me manda el de la primera posición id_contacto[0]; pero quiero mandar el arreglo entero, gracias por su ayuda

la parte del html es así, los datos se llenan con una consulta

```html
<select class="select2_multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" id="id_contacto_solicita[]">
                                <option value="">Choose option</option>
                                  <option value="27">ADRIAN CANTU</option>
                                  <option value="3">ALEJANDRO VALLEJO</option>
                                  <option value="4">ANAYATZIN JIMENEZ</option>
                                  <option value="15">CITY EXPRESS</option>
                                  <option value="13">CLARA RAMIREZ</option>
                                  <option value="14">CLAUDIA CAMACHO</option>
                                  <option value="8">CRISTIAN REYES</option>
                                  <option value="20">DOLORES GALICIA</option>
                                  <option value="19">ENRIQUE MENESES</option>
                                  <option value="17">Ferring</option>
                                  <option value="11">FREDDY ORTIZ</option>
                                  <option value="23">GERARDO</option>
                                  <option value="18">JANETH MENDEZ</option>
                                  <option value="7">JOSUE VILLALOBOS</option>
                                  <option value="2">JUAN MORALES</option>
                                  <option value="5">KARINA BAUTISTA</option>
                                  <option value="6">LUIS SILVA</option>
                                  <option value="26">MARCO TREVIÑO</option>
                                  <option value="21">MARIVEL</option>
                                  <option value="10">MATI</option>
                                  <option value="16">MONSERRAT</option>
                                  <option value="12">PATRICIA</option>
                                  <option value="24">ROSA ZAMARRIPA</option>
                                  <option value="1">SARA MORENO</option>
                              </select>
```

Comment: saludos podrias agregar como esta formado tu html "id_contacto_solicita" , para poder darte una mejor respuesta..!!

Comment: Ya eh actualizado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saludos para obtener los valores seleccionados debes usar un identificador unico para tu **dropdown multiple** tomando de ejemplo tu select multiple(dropdown multiple):

```js
function obtenerValores(){
  var fld = document.getElementById('id_contacto_solicita');
  var values = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < fld.options.length; i++) {
    if (fld.options[i].selected) {
      values.push(fld.options[i].value);
    }
  }
  alert('Seleccionados: '+values);
}
```

```html
<select class="select2_multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" id="id_contacto_solicita">
  <option value="" disabled>Choose option</option>
  <option value="27">ADRIAN CANTU</option>
  <option value="3">ALEJANDRO VALLEJO</option>
  <option value="4">ANAYATZIN JIMENEZ</option>
  <option value="15">CITY EXPRESS</option>
  <option value="13">CLARA RAMIREZ</option>
  <option value="14">CLAUDIA CAMACHO</option>
  <option value="8">CRISTIAN REYES</option>
  <option value="20">DOLORES GALICIA</option>
  <option value="19">ENRIQUE MENESES</option>
  <option value="17">Ferring</option>
  <option value="11">FREDDY ORTIZ</option>
  <option value="23">GERARDO</option>
  <option value="18">JANETH MENDEZ</option>
  <option value="7">JOSUE VILLALOBOS</option>
  <option value="2">JUAN MORALES</option>
  <option value="5">KARINA BAUTISTA</option>
  <option value="6">LUIS SILVA</option>
  <option value="26">MARCO TREVIÑO</option>
  <option value="21">MARIVEL</option>
  <option value="10">MATI</option>
  <option value="16">MONSERRAT</option>
  <option value="12">PATRICIA</option>
  <option value="24">ROSA ZAMARRIPA</option>
  <option value="1">SARA MORENO</option>
</select><br>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="obtenerValores();">Obtener Seleccionados</a>
```

**Explicación**

Basicamente lo que hago es recorrer uno a uno cada option mediante un ciclo for y verifico si fue seleccionado y en caso de serlo obtengo su ID y lo agrego a un array.

Con esto ya puedes hacer el envio normal..

Espero te sirva y suerte..!!

Comment: Genio!!!!!, a la primera quedo.

Comment: a tu función solo agregue return values; en la funcion de ajax y funciono a la primera